# Android Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I need to user choice their own player to play video and I try

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String videoUrl = "http://someurl/video.mp4";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
        i.setData(Uri.parse(videoUrl));  
        startActivity(i); 
}
```

But in my example activity open browser not a list of current installed player.
Which option of Intent I should use? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
String videoUrl = "http://someurl/video.mp4";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoUrl),"video/mp4");  
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The schema is "http", so the webview will be open.

this is a stream video, try to download it firstly. and then open it.

Comment: Thank you ! You are right, but if I use "Nik...." example I can select browser or player. But in my example url directly opens in default browser.