# Want to download this pdf file

Tags: android

When I click the `Button` it open the `link` and ask me what program I want to open `pdf`. Then it pop's up a message box and says `file has (0 byte) cant open.`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void browser1(View view){
        Intent BrowserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://www.docdroid.net/file/download/mUaJciS/contatos-lubrifuel.pdf"));
        startActivity(BrowserIntent);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Download the file, first, then use ACTION_VIEW to open it locally.

Comment: this will help to download the file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your PDF is accessible.
Check this discussion:
[Android Intent.ACTION_VIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430073/android-intent-action-view)

Or do this:
Pass the URL parameter as extra to your WebView Activity:

```
public void browser1(View view){

  Intent BrowserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  String PDFurl = "http://www.docdroid.net/file/download/mUaJciS/contatos-lubrifuel.pdf";
  BrowserIntent.putExtra("PDFUrl", PDFurl);
  startActivity(BrowserIntent);
}
```

Then in your started activity call (into the onCreate method)

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_webview);
String PDFurl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PDFUrl");
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webview.loadUrl(PDFurl);
```